# Getting relational data into arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have a animal table:

```
id | name
1    cat
2    dog
```

I have a breeds table:

```
id | breed    |          color
1    siamese             white     
2    tabby               mixed
3    golden retriever    yellow
```

I have a animal to breeds table:

```
id | animal_id | breed_id
1         1          1
2         1          2
3         2          3
```

I want to get out each animal and all of its breeds/colors into an array which I'll then pass to JS.

So the data should look like:

```
array('animal' => 'cat', 'details' => array(array('breed' => 'siamese', 'color' => 'white'), array('breed' => 'tabby', 'color' => 'mixed')) 'animal' => 'dog...etc);
```

I'm not sure on the query though? I need to get data for all animals.

Comment: I think your Animaltobreed table is overkilling as usually I never see same Breed been used for 2 animal, so you can simply put animalid in Breed table against each row, and then it is simpler for you.

Comment: Select * from animal join animal_2_breed on animal.animal_id = animal_2_breed.animal_id join breeds on animal_2_breed.breed_id = breeds.breed_id where animal.name = "cat"

Comment: @Bogdan I need to get all records for all animals

Comment: @panthro Then remove the "where" clause at the end and you will get all the animals. The result will besomething like: 1 = cat - siamese - white; 2 = cat - tabby - mixed; 3 = dog - golden retriever - yellow. After that you can use  php to recover one line at a time and build your associative array as you please.

Comment: how would you build the array in php?

Comment: @panthro see my answer for the complete query and how to build it into an array.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
$query = "SELECT a.name, b.breed, b.colour 
    FROM animals a
    LEFT JOIN animaltobreeds ab on a.id = ab.animal_id
    LEFT JOIN breeds b on b.id = ab.breed_id";
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = array(); // We'll build our results into here.
if($results->num_rows) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        if( ! isset($data[$row['name']]) $data[$row['name']] = array();
        $data[$row['name']][] = array(
            'breed'     => $row['breed'],
            'colour'    => $row['colour']
        );
    }
}
```

Then if you want to output it for Javascript you can turn it into JSON by using `json_encode($data)`, then import it into Javascript.

You may notice I've done a slightly different structure to the one you requested, this one will look like this:

```
array('cats' => array('breed => 'siamese', 'colour' => 'white'), array('breed' => 'tabby', 'color' => 'mixed'));
```

I think it's easier to work with, but it should be easy enough to adjust if you really need it to be what you want it to be.